# Error when run substrate-front-end-template$ yarn install

Tags: substrate

I have been following the instruction to  Install the Front-end template , error when I run  substrate-front-end-template$ yarn install.The error is following:

Error: Cannot find module 'worker_threads'
## Heading ##at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules cjs/loader.js:636:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
at /home/erichuang2005/substrate-node-template/substrate-front-end-template/.yarn/releases/yarn-berry.cjs:289:2658

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your exact error message but I also had a problem with `yarn install` which was solved by using a different version of node. I had a problem with version 17. Version 16 worked for me.